# Need help to understand Merkle Tree

Tags: data-structures, merkle-tree

I am trying to design a feature which verifies consistency of data across various networking switches. Number of the data is in millions and this data is replicated in different networking switches. I am considering Merkle tree to implement this feature because that way I do not have send data across network for verification. However I have a doubt regarding the Merkle tree. Let's say I have two Merkle trees. If the root-hash of each tree matches each other then can I conclude that both trees are mirror image of each other? And if yes the does this property hold true for other inter-mediate nodes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [Merkle tree for difference comparison, in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795047/merkle-tree-for-difference-comparison-in-cassandra). If the root hash are same then it can be concluded that rest of tree hence the stub nodes, representing data blocks, are identical.